# Using empty edits for the sake of bumping a question

Tags: support, edits, bump

Recently I stumbled across a question which was posted some 12 hours ago and was edited by the author 17 times since. However, all but two edit were reverted by that same user during the grace period. There were times in the question's life where this happened four times in a single hour. In the edit history this shows up as a list of revisions with no actual change:

[image]

(Lest I might be mistaken on this one, I will, at least for now, not include any details about the question or the author to spare them the possibly unjust Meta effect.)

Since even the empty edit will actually bump the question, this somehow has a smell of misuse to it. Looking at the author's question history one notices, that this behaviour has occurred beforehand on other questions. The user—having short of 600 rep—is obviously aware of how the site works and how to get attention to their questions as they have an active bounty on one of their other questions. But even that question was null-edited numerous times before and after the bounty was placed on it.

Although this is not a major issue, it starts to get annoying, because I closely monitor the activity in that tag and found myself repeatedly being lured into looking at it in search for any real updates.

Am I possibly misinterpreting this pattern? If not, is the behaviour generally accepted, tolerated or is it frowned upon on SO?

Comment: Yes, this is abuse. If you see something like this happening, please raise a moderator flag on the question so one of us can take a look at it.

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks for the clarification! I just raised the moderator flag on one of the questions. Shame on me for not having found the other resources; I thought, I had thoroughly researched the topic. I am obviously stronger on SO than I am on Meta.

Comment: The user responsible has been warned, because this is clearly abuse.

Comment: @BradLarson maybe caching or weird race condition (timing IS very close), but seems it didn't take.... one of the user's questions was bumped 4 minutes ago, and you commented here 7 minutes ago.. so maybe he was warned after your comment, not before... but it sure looks like he isn't learning :/

Comment: @Patrice - People don't always read warnings right away. They just did, and indicated this will stop.

Comment: @BradLarson makes sense. Not having ever received such a warning, I don't know how "intrusive" they are, and how easily they can be disregarded. Forget my comment then, thanks for following up :)

Comment: Before 2014-04 posts turned into community wiki after a certain number of edits (thus denying any further reputation points gain and punishing this kind of abuse). See e.g. (cross site): [an answer to *Can we disable automatic community wiki conversion for answer edits?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203616/can-we-disable-automatic-community-wiki-conversion-for-answer-edits/228947#228947).

Comment: con't: There is supposed to be an automatic flag for moderators: *"We have disabled all forms of community wiki automatic conversions, not just for answers but for questions as well. The feature was never really about encouraging substantive edits as much as it was about prevent abuse. ... flags are now raised for moderator attention in the event of several edits."*