# Re-Editing tags can put you on the "newest" category

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, edits, bump

If you go to one of your oldest questions, remove a tag (save) and then put it again, it will put you on the "Newest" category of that tag.

[image]

Comment: Your "bug" report is that editing a question will bump it to the top? That's not a bug; that's expected, documented behavior.

Comment: I think they might be saying it bumps the question in the "newest" tab instead of "active" (I may misremember, but I think it's supposed to only bump it there), @CodyGray. Not sure, though. Bella?

Comment: As [I previously noted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358387/using-empty-edits-for-the-sake-of-bumping-a-question?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment525577_358387), doing this to "bump" your own question is considered an abuse of the system. Do not make a habit of doing it, and do not continue "testing" it.

Comment: No repro, @Oleg. [That bumped question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72337784/revisions) still shows up in its original sort order for the [tag:python] tag.

Comment: hmm, indeed it does, @CodyGray. I do not understand what the report is about then (but you never know with SE these days...)

Comment: @CodyGray it does not show up in its original sort order. It directly goes to the latest post on my screen. I would have shown a screenshot but I didn't take one when I "tested" it. You said not to "test" it again, so just try it yourself.

Comment: "*It directly goes to the latest post on my screen.*" it's still unclear what happened, and what you said shouldn't have happened. But if I have to guess: you opened the question from the "newest" tab, edited the question, then used the "back" navigation from the browser back to the "newest" tab. If that's the case, then it's by design because the old question list is cached on the browser, until you refresh it.